# How can a truck network be built / extracted using osm2po?

Tags: osm2po

Is it possible to adjust the config of osm2po to build a truck / lorry (in German: LKW) network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?  It just depends on the tags given by OSM.  You can restrict everything in osm2po.  For example: If a street restricts vehicles over 7 tons, there must be a tag for it.  If so, just compare the following example with the default config:

```
wtr.flagList = truck
wtr.finalMask = truck

wtr.tag.highway.motorway = 1, 11, 80, truck
... etc.

# just an example, don't know if such a tag exist in OSM
wtr.deny.tons.7 = truck
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't implying that it wasn't possible. I adjusted my config as you suggest (replacing car with truck, and not using the tons.7 stuff), but now I get ther Error: FATAL  Exception at Thu Aug 15 13:19:37 CEST 2013
       Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
       Class: java.lang.RuntimeException
       Stacktrace:
       de.cm.osm2po.converter.Tiler.<init>(Tiler.java:98)
       de.cm.osm2po.Main.runTiler(Main.java:177)
       de.cm.osm2po.Main.main(Main.java:125)

Comment: Coming to think of it, it'll probably suffice to adjust the speeds, since I do not really care about spefic truck hights etc. on the way. Did I already say that osm2po is awesome! :)

Comment: don't forget to set `maxSpeedOverrides=false` then.

Comment: But I'm still interested in the error thrown above. Can you send me the corresponding config which caused it?

Comment: sorry, but how best to send you the config file?

Comment: btw. thank ouy for the maxSpeedOverrides tip. Am using it now. will send you config, once I know to where.

Comment: I sent it to your info address.

Comment: Thanks to Carsten. He pointed out to me, that the config file parameters are case sensitive, so (in my case) it must read wtr.flagList = truck. Et Voila, it worked. :)

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. See my example given above.